# How can you find the 3d period of a summation of plane waves?

Tags: periodic-functions

I realize this is a very hard question. In the very least I'd like to know  *if there is a way to do this or not*.

Say you have a summation of plane waves in a 3d volume, with longitudinal and transverse components.

[image: water]

[Actually I'm trying to model water](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yv8jZyQ3kV0&feature=plcp). What I'm trying to do is figure out the "cubic period" - the size of the **3d volume** that repeats.

[This document](http://www.utdallas.edu/~cpb021000/EE%203302/Additional%20Reading/Period%20of%20Sum%20of%20Tones.doc) says the period of the sum of sinuosoids is the LCM of the denominator of their periods, e.g.

The period of

$$
y(t) = \sin\left( \frac{2\pi t}{6} \right) + \cos\left( \frac{2\pi t}{6} \right) + 
\sin\left( \frac{2\pi 7 t}{2} \right) + \sin\left( \frac{2\pi t}{4} \right) 
$$

is

$$
LCM( 6,6,2,4 ) = 12
$$

Indeed a quick sketch shows it appears to work,

[image: I believe it]

Now my question is, how would I go about extending this to three dimensions?

Comment: Your waves look like something like $\exp k \cdot z$? Should be straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For water, you should probably be thinking in two dimensions, because the surface of the water is two dimensional.  The waves are then amplitudes in the $z$ direction.  If you have two orthogonal waves, it will be like $z=\cos \left(\frac{2\pi x}5\right)+ \cos \left(\frac{2\pi y}3\right)$.  The repeat is a rectangle, $5$ units in $x$ by $3$ units in $y$.  If you have two non-orthogonal waves, the repeat is a parallelogram with sides in the two directions.  If you have waves in more than two directions, there may not be a repeat.

Comment: Actually 2 dimensional waves don't give you the "shifting" (longitudinal motion) along the surface of the sea. What I'm worried about is _yes_, there might not be a repeat when the waves are allowed arbitrary 3-space direction.

Comment: @bobobobo:  You can get the shifting by making the amplitude be a vector that can point in various directions.  The waves still propagate only in two dimensions.  There will be a repeat as long as there are no more independent waves than dimensions.  Even in one dimension, there may not be a repeat if the period of two waves are not rationally related.  I don't know what condition applies if you have more waves than dimensions to make a repeat.

Comment: Interesting approach.  So perhaps I allow waves to have amplitude on _both_ longitudinal and traverse axes.

Comment: In a usual wind wave, the motion of the particles of water is known to be (approximately) a circle centered on the rest location.  So for a wave in the $x$ direction, you have the position $p=\hat z \cos (\omega t)+\hat x \sin (\omega t)$